# Validate multiple image format in JS in multipler file uploader

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I wanna validate images format during `submit` or `onchange` which will browse by multiple file up loader.

But after `Google` and on SO i am can't find multiple image browse validation in `JS` script.. 
Here is `HTML`

```
<input type="file" id='uploadImg' name='uploadImg[]' multiple >
<input id="imgaeupload" value="Submit" type="submit" name='uploadImage'/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files property of the file upload element holds the list of selected files, you can iterate over the list and validate each file:

```
 function validate() {
    var uploadImg = document.getElementById('uploadImg');
    //uploadImg.files: FileList
    for (var i = 0; i < uploadImg.files.length; i++) {
       var f = uploadImg.files[i];
       if (!endsWith(f.name, 'jpg') && !endsWith(f.name,'png')) {
           alert(f.name + " is not a valid file!");
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;

       }
    }
}

function endsWith(str, suffix) {
   return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: Simple but great solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Make Common function in javascript for image upload validation**

1. *In HTML file*

   ```
   &lt;input type="file" name="productImage_name[]" multiple="multiple" onchange="imageTest(this)"&gt;
   ```
2. *In Java Script file*

   ```
    function imageTest(field){
       var regex =  /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/i; // Check file type .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif etc.

    var target = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
    // target = http:  //  localhost  /  KapdaSearch/V1/Development/public/company

    var fileUploadPath = target.replace(/public.*/, "public/storage/images/"); // Here 1st parameter is regular expression 2nd is replace string with
    // fileUploadPath = http://localhost/KapdaSearch/V1/Development/public/storage/images/

   //alert(field.value); // It gives you fake path of file because of some security reason like C:/fakepath/abc.png
   // We need only file name so use field.files[0].name instead of field.value

   // Image validation when you select multiple images at once
    for(var i=0; i<field.files.length; i++){
   var fieldName = field.files[i].name; // Guess file name = xyz.png   

   var imgPath = fileUploadPath+fieldName; 
   // http://localhost/KapdaSearch/V1/Development/public/storage/images/xvz.png
   // Check file type is correct or not
   if(fieldName.match(regex)){
       // Check file already exist or not
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.open('HEAD', imgPath, false);
       xmlhttp.send();
       if (xmlhttp.status == "404") {
           field.setCustomValidity('');
       } else {
           field.setCustomValidity('This '+fieldName+' is already exist. Change file name than upload..');
       }
   }
   else{
       field.setCustomValidity('This '+fieldName+' is invalid..');
   }
   } //End for loop
   } // End function
   ```